# How to dismiss Android Notification in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Flutter app and would like to add push notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Using the Firebase dashboard I can send a push notification which is received by the emulator. After dragging the notification drawer down and tapping on the notification my app opens. However, the notification remains in the system notification drawer.

How can I make the notification disappear once it's been tapped?

Here is my Flutter code for setting up notification handling:

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  debugPrint('Got a message whilst in the background!');
  debugPrint("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

class PushMessagingController {
  static Future<void> initialise() async {
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is to make sure the notification icon is specified in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
```